# Как отладить обфусцированную программу, декомпилированную fernflower'ом или приключения джуниора?

Tags: java, декомпиляция, обратная-разработка

Честно говоря ни чем таким раньше не занимался, однако передо мной стоит задача разобрать писанину предыдущего разраба, который психанув, ушёл из проекта, и скажем так восстановить программу из последнего релиза, т.к. он забрал с собой сорцы. Я же совсем новенький в яве, мало чего ещё понимаю, но задачу эту повесили на меня.
Но чтож. Немного погуглив, нашёл наиболее хорошо оцениваемый декомпилятор/деобфускатор fernflower. Написал простенькую прогу, скомпилил, а потом декомпильнул ффом. Вроде годный, компилируемый сорц получился.
Потом принялся за работу над задачей: Программа в целом состояла из двух частей: стартер/апдейтер и собственно сама программа. Стартер апдейтит прогу при необходимости, после чего запускает её через SwingUtils.InvokeLater runnable ProccessBuilder. Я декомпильнул стартер, получившийся код впряг в новый проджект в моей любомой NetBeans IDE, определил и вынес либы, но код не стал декомпилиться: проблема оказалась в том, что где-то запрашивался класс, не присутствующий в жарнике стартера (крэшрепортер), также заметил что в этом же жарнике лежат "лишние" классы, т.е. те классы, которые вообще не из мира сего. И я сначала свалил всё на фф, но заглянув в папку, куда распаковал собственно жарник стартера (с компилированными классами), я обнаружил что действительно не хватает нужных классов. Тогда я решил, что стоит попробовать декомпильнуть второй жарник, и к моему величайшему удивлению, в нём оказался тот самый класс крэшрепортера, а пошарив по классам второго жарника, нашёл импорты "лишних" классов из первого o_0. Тут я понял, что если не решу это говнище, то меня наверняка выпрут с работы, я впаду в депрессию и сопьюсь, и с такой нехилой мотивацией начал искать и сравнивать с декомпиленными сорцами, в поисках используемой версии, кучу либ... Сейчас добавил больше половины, но при просмотре классов во втором жарнике, обнаружил, что они были обфусцированны, т.к. в большинстве случаев, названия переменных были аля var151 и так далее, но ещё больше меня поразило обилие классов вида a.class, aa.class, ab.class в основном пакете. Также во втором жарнике в классах нередко встречались конструкции аля:

```
        try {
           a = b();
        } catch (Exception var7) {
           ;
        }
```

И самое ужасное, что обфусцированный код второго жарника теперь кишит ошибками CannotFindSymbol...

Я знаю, что спрашивать несколько вопросов в одном - нехорошо, но разносить описание на кучу вопросов - тоже будет неправильно.
И как вы поняли дорогие друзья, я прошу вашей помощи:
 1. Как объяснить несказанно раскиданные классы (моё предположение, что стартер и основное приложение было одним проектом, а при сборке распихивалось по разным ярникам, т.к. иначе присутствие классов с ошибками импорта в скомпиленном проекте нельзя объяснить)
 2. Как быстро распутать белиберду в основном пакете. Может есть какой-то способ автоматом восстановить названия классов, свойств и методов, или всё придётся делать вручную?
 3. Как быстро определить версию используемой библиотеки, если нигде про неё не написано. Может есть какая-нибудь программа?
 4. Как легче всего отладить программу и убрать все эти непонятные конструкции и cannotfindsymbol'ы?

Спасибо, друзья!

Comment: Да, и если в вашей компании нету version control'а — тем более убегайте. Найдите себе нормальную компанию и работайте как белый человек.

Comment: @VladD, cvs есть, но внутренняя и там был собственно он один, я пришёл почти что за день до того как этот ушёл. Он меня не успел добавить и соответственно экземпляра сорцов не осталось, т.к. он снёс всё :) Спасибо за советы - надо будет спланировать побег из курятника) А пока будет здорово, если кто-нибудь поможет с этими вопросами, потому что действительно интересно, как например можно разнести классы по разным жарникам...

P.S. Попробовал убрать вызовы крешрепортера в try-catch... стартер скомпилировался и теперь вроде работает, однако что с основной программой - непонятно...

Comment: @VladD, снизу не хватило места, поэтому спрошу здесь. Я юзаю нетбинс и ставить эклипс и иже с ним для меня будет сущим адом, наверняка есть thread dumper'ы, не зависящие от IDE. Я нашёл [такую вещь](http://visualvm.java.net/). Она подойдёт для решения моих задач? Также я искал StackTrace от AdaptJ, но не нашёл. Я вообще в ту сторону ведь копаю? Спасибо!

Comment: @RussiaVodkaMatreshka: Мне сложно вам что-то посоветовать, я никогда не решал задач, подобных вашей, на Java. Просто попробуйте. Если оно хоть немного облегчит вашу задачу — уже плюс.

Для .NET похожие задачи помогают решать, например, программы [redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/), но они вроде бы для Java ничего не делают.

Comment: Эту задачу по идее стоит решать в правовом поле - исходники (если не было других договоренностей) собственность конторы. Могли бы пригрозить судом (который выиграли бы).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала, задание по восстановлению сорцов (то есть, логики) из декомпилята — задача не для джуниора, а для профи-специалиста. Если вам платят джуниорскую зарплату при этом — немедленно психуйте, убегайте и ищите себе нормальную работу. (Можете забрать с собой деобфусцированные исходники тоже.)

ЗЫ: из хорошей конторы ваш предшественник сломя голову не побежал бы.

---

Если вы и восстановите компилируемость, вам придётся разобраться в логике. Если вы всё же хотите набраться опыта — считайте декомпилированный код «намёком» на правильный, и раскидывайте куски по проектам вручную.

Насколько я понимаю, автоматически восстановить обфусцированные названия классов невозможно, если только обфускатор не сохранил где-то информацию о первоначальных именах. Пичалько.

Версия использованной библиотеки вполне может быть в метаданных (тут я не спец), поищите информацию. Если нет — придётся подбирать вручную.

По поводу непонятных конструкций — присмотритесь к ним, скорее всего, вы найдёте в них какую-то логику, и сможете быстро понять, где оригинальный код, а где добавка от обфускатора.

И ещё раз, помните, что это очень сложная и высококвалифицированная работа. Возможно, переписать проект с нуля будет более простым решением! И потребуйте хорошую премию, задание вам досталось *крайне* сложное.

Comment: Т.е. по сути следует придётся брать проект с декомпилятом, создать пустой проект и по мере разбора логики - переписывать всю программу, я правильно понял? А что насчёт всяких отладчиков... я слышал их как-то используют для обратного проектирования (брейк-поинты там и прочее), расскажете?
Спасибо, завтра же подам на премию! :)

P.S. Также нашёл пустые классы, наследуемые от пустых же интерфейсов, экземпляр которых создан в ходе программы и проигнорирован (просто new ov();). Это можно удалять вместе с фантомными классами? (Т.е. это проделки обфускатора?)

Comment: @RussiaVodkaMatreshka: Угу, так и есть. Скорее всего, придётся собирать проект заново по кусочкам.

Отладчик позволяет восстановить логику. Допустим, у вас кусок кода не работает, а в старой версии работал. Ставите в ней breakpoint и смотрите, какие входные значения (и откуда пришла программа в стеке), и на каком шаге пути выполнения кода расходятся.

---
Да, скорее всего обфускатор. Ничего не делает — выкидывайте, упрощайте код.

Comment: @VladD, обновил коммент.

---

Спасибо!)

Comment: @VladD, и я того же мнения) Кстати, попутный вопрос. Программа собиралась антом, но я слабо знаком со сборщиками вроде анта и мавена. В манифесте прописано Class-Path: ${library.libs.classpath}. Что это означает?

Comment: @VladD, обновил коммент выше! Т.е. это то, что пихают в  -Djava.library.path ?

Comment: @RussiaVodkaMatreshka: ну, в Ant'e есть внутренние переменные, `${library.libs.classpath}` — это подстановка значения переменной `library.libs.classpath`.

---
Хм, насчёт `-Djava.library.path` не знаю, я не спец в Java.

Answer (score 2):

декомпилируйте оба джарника совместно. Если декомпилятор не позволяет задавать 2 джарника, объедините их в один. Джарник это zip файл, просто по другому называется, так что объединять можно и ручками.

Comment: Сейчас попробую - отпишусь!

Comment: @rfq, @VladD, Я так впринципе и хотел сделать сначала, но решил попробовать поотдельности. Вообщем декомпильнул вместе, однако как было всё плохо, так и осталось. Например я нахожу в коде вызовы методы классов, называющихся в реале по другому (IC.z() = Version.loadVersion()). Может в байткоде смотреть что надо, потому что предыдущее я нашёл, ткнув пальцем в небо. Что насчёт этого скажете, потому как всё остальное я вроде успешно восстанавливаю... (Хоть и медленно :))

Comment: @RussiaVodkaMatreshka: мне кажется, лучше думать так: если где-то декомпиляция/деобфускация дала хороший, валидный код — это редкая удача. Если нет — что ж, придётся тыкать пальцем в небо (а если потом станет ясно предназначение, то переименовывать классы и методы).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо!
Тогда такой вопрос. Каждый метод что-то делает, не так ведь? Если я не знаю какой это метод, то я могу его найти по результату его деятельности. Соответственно как отследить изменения в памяти программы? Для это и нужны дебаггеры с точками останова? Какой тогда отладчик посоветуете? IDA Pro? Или есть более подходящие для моей ситуации? И собственно отладчики показывают изменения переменных у прерываний или только сами переменные?

Comment: В случае с java IDA  - слишком сильный инструмент.

Comment: @VladD, @KoVadim, в таком случае чем посоветуете воспользоваться, и где почитать на тему отладки внешнего приложения (т.е. не та отладка как в IDE, а чтобы можно было посмотреть в оригинале, что меняется в памяти после выполнения метода байт-кода, или никакой разницы в этих вещах нет и я просто туплю?)

Comment: @RussiaVodkaMatreshka: Хм. Посмотрите [сюда](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1905446/276994) и [сюда](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19843096/276994). Готовых удобных решений нет, вам придётся повозиться и смириться со значительными неудобствами. Я ж говорил, задача у вас реально непростая.